# android.widget.SeekBar cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, xml

I am creating a brightness control dialog. However the problem I am having is that when I put textview then seekbar it causes this error:

> android.widget.SeekBar cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

For some reason it seems to work when the positioning on .xml follows seekbar then textview.

Here is some code:

```
LayoutInflater li_brightness = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v_brightness = li_brightness.inflate(R.layout.options_dialog_brightness, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ll_brightness_layout));
            bright_textView = (TextView)v_brightness.findViewById(R.id.brightness_text);
            brightBar = (SeekBar)v_brightness.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_brightness);
            confirm_brightness = (Button)v_brightness.findViewById(R.id.button_brightness);



            cResolver = getContentResolver();

            window = getWindow();

            brightBar.setMax(100);
            brightBar.setProgress(50);
            brightBar.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

            bright_textView.setText("50".toString());


            brightBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    float BackLightValue = (float)progress/100;
                    if(BackLightValue <= 0){
                        bright_textView.setText(String.valueOf(BackLightValue));
                    }


                      WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
                      layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
                      getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Add logcat and XML ,I think but not sure,the problem due to your id from XML layout file You give id of textview to Seekbar check it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try cleaning your project (Project > Clean from Eclipse or `ant clean` from the command line), and see if that clears up your problem. Sometimes the build system gets a bit out of sync with itself in terms of the `R` values, and this sort of error is one of the symptoms.

Comment: You are completely correct. For some reason I tried this before it didn't work.